# Why do I get an error when I use the array function

Tags: arrays, vba, autocad

I tested this Autocad VBA routine. It worked. No problem.

```
Sub Add_Line_1()
    Dim n1(2) As Double, n2(2) As Double
    Dim r As AcadLine
    n1(0) = 100
    n1(1) = 150

    n2(0) = 220
    n2(1) = 230
    Set r = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.AddLine(n1, n2)
End Sub
```

But. I want to use `Array` function. It not worked. An error occurred.

> Run-time Error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument

```
Sub Add_Line_2()
    Dim n1 As Variant, n2 As Variant
    Dim r As AcadLine
    n1 = Array(100#, 150#)
    n2 = Array(220#, 230#)

    ' ERROR LINE.
    Set r = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.AddLine(n1, n2)
End Sub
```

How to use `Array` function in this code?

**EDIT:**
I tried this code but again error

> Compile error. Can't assign to array

```
Sub Add_Line_3()
    Dim n1(2) As Double, n2(2) As Double
    Dim r As AcadLine
    n1 = Array(100#, 150#, 0#) 'ERROR LINE
    n2 = Array(220#, 230#, 0#)

    Set r = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.AddLine(n1, n2)
End Sub
```

Comment: try `Dim n1(YourNumber To YourNumber) As Variant, n2(YourNumber To YourNumber) As Variant`
In  `sub Add_Line_1()` you have `Dim N1(2)` but in `sub Add_Line_2()` you dont.

you also set the `acadline` wrong. you don't give an index for the array

Comment: The short answer?  You can't.  The AddLine call is expecting a 3-element array of doubles while the Array function is returning a variant array.  These are not equivalent.

Comment: Why do you want to use the Array function?  To save lines of code?  If so, you could do this:  `n1(0) = 100: n1(1) = 150`.

Comment: @Nemoko I tried `Dim n1(2)` in `Add_Line_2` but error occured: Can't assign to array

Comment: @BrianMStafford I think coding with the array function is more understandable, readable and editable.

Comment: AutoCAD is very picky about variable types. Do not use `Variant` https://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2017/ENU/?guid=GUID-26C95029-14BB-40B9-9987-49EFC980CB9D

Comment: @braX I used Double instead Variant in Add_Line_3. But again error occured

Answer (score 1):

If it's just about streamlining the code, you can use a helper function.

Assuming that we are talking about a point in 2D/3D space, we could define:

```
Function Point(x As Double, y As Double, Optional z As Double = 0) As Double()
    ReDim temp(2) As Double
    temp(0) = x
    temp(1) = y
    temp(2) = z
    Point = temp
End Function
```

and use

```
ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.AddLine(Point(100, 150), Point(220, 230))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. my goal is to use `Array` function for point values

Comment: @Mesut You can't, period. As the others have told you.